# Net-SNMP No community name specified error

Tags: snmp, net-snmp

I'm trying to use snmptable to do some exercises on a remote UNIX machine(mlb1). I need to access another SNMP agent(mlb2) at port 1611. I want to get the `sysORTable` whose OID is `1.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1`, so I use the `snmptable` command.

`snmptable -Ci -Cb -v 2c udp:mlb2:1161 .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1`

However, I always get an error.

```
No community name specified.
USAGE: snmptable [OPTIONS] AGENT TABLE-OID
Version:  5.5
```

What's wrong with my command? I'm grateful to you for pointing out my error.

Comment: This question does not seem to involve programming, but only a command line tool. Perhaps it would be a better fit for ServerFault.com or superuser.com?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should specify community string if you use **SNMPv2c**. To do that use *-c* option:
**Example:** *-c public*

Comment: I have specified -c option. Still facing this issue. My command: snmpget -v 2c <IP> -c public .1.3.6.1.2.1.10.127.1.3.3.1